# does smooks support json output

Tags: json, smooks

Does smooks support json output or thirdparty plugin for json?

For example, to do XML-to-JSON or EDI-to-JSON

I see it has json reader/parser, but can't seem to find an output/writer.

TIA!

Comment: did you find a handly solution or tutorial for converting EDI to JSON or XML? if yes please comment and help me . tnx

Answer (score 1):

Not directly, but it would support populating of a Java Object model from e.g. XML or EDI and then you could use something like Jackson to serialize the Java to JSON. So should be easy enough to do once you get the data into a Java Object model.

Also note that you do not need to create an actual Java Object model. You can create what Smooks calls a "virtual object model", which is basically collection types (Maps, Lists etc).